# When receiving "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)", how can I force the program to ignore and continue?

Tags: python, opencv, enumerate, orb, flann

I am using Python (3) and OpenCV (3.3) to run live object detection on a webcam, using a sample image which then is feature matches to the video stream. I have got it to work using SIFT/SURF but am trying to use ORB algorithm.

I am receiving the following error in some cases causing the program to crash:

```
for i, (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I understand the reasons behind it crashing, sometimes there are good matches between images, and sometimes there aren't, causing a mismatch.

My question is, how do I force the program to ignore and skip the cases where there are not enough values and continue running.

Main area of code in question:

```py
    for i, (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
            good.append(m)
```

Example 'matches' output:

```
[[<DMatch 0x11bdcc030>, <DMatch 0x11bbf20b0>], [<DMatch 0x11bbf2490>, <DMatch 0x11bbf24f0>], [<DMatch 0x11bbf2750>, <DMatch 0x11bbf25d0>], [<DMatch 0x11bbf2570>, <DMatch 0x11bbf2150>], etc etc
```

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import os, os.path
import math
import time
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10   # default=10

img1 = cv2.imread('Pattern3_small.jpg',0)          # queryImage

# Create ORB object. You can specify params here or later.
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture("output_H264_30.mov")

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)

pts_global = []
dst_global = []

position = []
heading = []
# plt.axis([0, 1280, 0, 720])

tbl_upper_horiz = 1539
tbl_lower_horiz = 343
tbl_upper_vert = 1008
tbl_lower_vert = 110

# cv2.namedWindow("Frame", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# cv2.resizeWindow("Frame", 600,350)

while True:
    _, img2 = cap.read()

    # Start timer
    timer = cv2.getTickCount()

    # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
    # kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
    FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
    # index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
    index_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                   table_number = 6, # 12, 6
                   key_size = 12,     # 20, 12
                   multi_probe_level = 1) #2, 1
    search_params = dict(checks = 50)

    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

    # print (matches)

    # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
    fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []

    # ratio test as per Lowe's paper
    for i, (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
            good.append(m)

# Do something afterwards
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `a, *b = ...` The * forces the rest of the values to be packed back into b

Comment: Or catch and ignore the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat each element of `matches` as a collection and use exception handling:

```
for i, pair in enumerate(matches):
    try:
        m, n = pair
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
            good.append(m)

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this:

`for i, (m, n) in enumerate(matches):`

and you cannot guarantee that all tuples will always contain two elements, then you should do something like:

`for i, values in enumerate(matches):
   if len(values) < 2:
     continue # you don't have the second element to compare against
   ...
   # Do your usual processing here`

The code above is explicit and readable, i.e it's clear that you need two elements to proceed further in the processing chain. It is also less error prone since you're making sure you have the correct data to proceed on. It also allows you to count how many tuples were discarded.